# Scope implications when creating unordered_map values within member functions?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map` (as below, as a member of a class) that undergoes a large number of additions and removals of keys. Such additions and removals happen within member functions that have the following strategy. They populate a locally created `unordered_map` (of the same type as the original member), and finally the keys and the associated vector values are transferred to the class member.

Is this strategy appropriate? Will the scope rules for the locally created `unordered_map` have an effect on the class member? Thanks for the support!

```
typedef std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int> > mapStruct;

class foo {
mapStruct DS;

void f() {
   mapStruct DS_tmp;
   DS_tmp[1].push_back(5);
   DS_tmp[1].push_back(10);
   ...
   ...
   mapStruct::iterator it = DS_tmp.begin();
   while( it != DS_tmp.end() ) {
      DS[it->first] = it->second;
   }
}

};
```

Comment: you can use `DS.insert(DS_tmp.begin(), DS_tmp.end());`.

Comment: Why not just put the values in the member variable?

Comment: @clcto I've hidden some details here purposefully to avoid any confusion. The `push_back`ed values are themselves obtained from the current structure in the member variable. We don't want to alter the member in place.

Comment: What prevents you from using the member variable instead of a temporary? Also, it seems hour doing initialization of the map, so you could populate the map in the constructor of the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code stops you from getting rid of `DS_tmp` and using `DS` directly in function `f`. But if due to some reasons you want to first fill temporary local variable and then copy it to the member, you can use `swap` instead of the `while` loop (which will never end by the way, because you are not incrementing `it`):

```
DS.swap(DS_tmp);
```